# 'R' geom_jitter() mixes symbols from two factor categories

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am drawing a geom_boxplot() with three samples, and for each sample I have two conditions.  I can draw the boxplot and set color and linetype() to distinguish the samples and conditions, but when I add a geom_jitter() and try to use different shapes for the different conditions, the shapes are spread across both of the two box plots (one for each condition):
[image]

In this example, the open circles should align with the dashed boxes, and the filled circles with the solid boxes.

How can I keep the symbols in the same column as the condition. I have tried group=cond  as well as shape=cond.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably looking for `position_jitterdodge()`. Note that the boxplot dodges the position and the points are jittered across their x-axis position. To have the points follow the boxes, you can use the aforementioned jitterdodge position adjustment. Example below:

```r
library(ggplot2)

df <- iris
df$subgroup <- sample(LETTERS[1:2], nrow(df), replace = TRUE)

ggplot(df, aes(Species, Sepal.Width)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(colour = subgroup)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour = subgroup),
             position = position_jitterdodge())
```

[image]